Inconveniente en inserción de registros a dos tablas que tiene una relación de uno a uno en Access
Cordial saludo espero se encuentren muy bien, les escribo para preguntarles el siguiente inconveniente que se me presenta al momento de realizar la inserción de registros a dos tablas que tienen una relación de uno a uno dentro de Access, en el lenguaje VBA:
El código que tengo es el siguiente:
Dim dbs As DAO.Database
Set dbs = CurrentDb()

DoCmd.SetWarnings False
Dim datosSQL, datosSQL1 As String

datosSQL = "INSERT INTO DMC ([IMEI],[S/N],[FCC ID], [Tipo_usuario],[Simcard],[Usunormal],[Contrasenormal],[Estado], [Usuprueba],[Contraseprueba],[Equivalencia]) " & _
 "VALUES(" & Form!txtDmcimei & ",'" & Form!txtSN & "','" & Form!txtFCCID & "','" & Form!txtDMCTU & "','" & Form!txtsimc & "','" & Form!txtUsunormal & "','" & Form!txtcontrnormal & "')" & _
 "('" & Form!txtEstado & "','" & Form!txtUsuprueba & "','" & Form!txtcontraprueba & "'," & Form!txtEquivalencia & ")"
 
 datosSQL1 = "INSERT INTO Usuario(a) ([NumIdent],[Nombre],[Tipo_usuario],[IMEI]) " & _
 "VALUES('" & Form!txtNumIdent & "','" & Form!txtnombre & "','" & Form!txtusutu & "'," & Form!txtUsuimei & ")"


DoCmd.RunSQL datosSQL
DoCmd.RunSQL datosSQL1
DoCmd.SetWarnings True

Al ejecutar el código me muestra el siguiente error el interpretador de VBA:
Se ha producido el error ‘3346’ en tiempo de ejecución:
El número de valores de consulta y el número de campos de destino son diferentes
He realizado la verificación y en las dos consultas como se ve, se evidencia que el numero de registros que se desean insertar en la consulta, coincide con el número de campos, no entiendo que es lo que estará sucediendo.
Atentamente
Hernán Martínez

Revisa el campo Form!txtcontrnormal y el que le sigue, Form!txtEstado. No los estás separando por una coma en tu query y, al ejecutarla, concatena ambos campos en uno y por eso te dice que te son diferentes.
